# Orderby By column's Number

Tags: c#, vb.net, sqlkata

How can specify the order clause by column number from the select like this:

Select colA, colB , colC from table order by 2 desc, 3,1 Desc

Comment: `order by colB desc, colC,colA Desc` ?  It's not really clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use Linq :

```
table.OrderByDescending(x => x.ColB).ThenBy(x => x.ColC).ThenByDescending(x => x.ColA);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you translate the `select` into a SQLKata `Select`:

```
var cols = new[] { "colA", "colB", "colC" };

... Select(cols).OrderByDesc(cols[2-1]).OrderBy(cols[3-1]).OrderByDesc(cols[1-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use anything other than columns names, you have to use the `OrderByRaw` method.

Check this example [SqlKata playground: OrderByRaw](https://sqlkata.com/playground?code=var%20query%20%3D%20new%20Query(%22t1%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Select(%22ColA%22%2C%20%22ColB%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.OrderByRaw(%221%20desc%2C%202%22))
Or take a look on the documentation [OrderByRaw documentation](https://sqlkata.com/docs/order#orderbyraw)

```
var query = new Query("t1")
    .Select("ColA", "ColB")
    .OrderByRaw("1 desc, 2")
```